# Go unit test is running packages imported from "go get" command

Tags: unit-testing, go

I imported a package "gopkg.in/yaml.v2".
this is under directory structure

```
src/
  gopkg.in/
    yaml.v2
  main.go
  abc.go
  abc_test.go
```

when I run the command `go test -v ./...` during build time its running unit test from imported package `gopkg.in/yaml.v2` as well. Which is not needed in my case.

I am new to Go and its testing framework. Did search in google for answer but could not find anything specific for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The go tool runs tests of all packages because you instruct it to.

The 3 dots `...` is a feature of the go tool, it means the given package and all packages found in its subfolders. Quoting from the doc of [Command Go: Description of package lists:](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Description_of_package_lists)

> An import path is a pattern if it includes one or more "..." wildcards, each of which can match any string, including the empty string and strings containing slashes. Such a pattern expands to all package directories found in the GOPATH trees with names matching the patterns.
>
> To make common patterns more convenient, there are two special cases. First, /... at the end of the pattern can match an empty string, so that net/... matches both net and packages in its subdirectories, like net/http. Second, any slash-separated pattern element containing a wildcard never participates in a match of the "vendor" element in the path of a vendored package, so that ./... does not match packages in subdirectories of ./vendor or ./mycode/vendor, but ./vendor/... and ./mycode/vendor/... do. Note, however, that a directory named vendor that itself contains code is not a vendored package: cmd/vendor would be a command named vendor, and the pattern cmd/... matches it. See golang.org/s/go15vendor for more about vendoring.

If you just want to run tests of your own package, don't append the `...` to it. Navigate to your package, then run `go test .`. Or from any folder, run `go test your/package`.

Of course to be able to do that (and it's recommended anyway), you should put your code into a package, and not into the `$GOPATH/src` folder directly. E.g. put it into the folder `$GOPATH/src/my/example`. Then you can test it like `go test my/example`.